# Query all and consistency

Tags: cassandra, nodes, nosql

This is a question regarding the behavior of cassandra for a select * query.
It's more for understanding, I know that normaly I should not execute such a query.

Assuming I have 4 Nodes with RF=2.
Following table (column family):
create table test_storage (
    id text,
    created_on TIMESTAMP,
    location int,
    data text,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
I inserted 100 entries into the table.

Now I do a select * from test_storage via cqlsh. Doing the query multiple times I get different results, so not all entries. When changing consistency to local_quorum I always get back the complete result. Why is this so? 
I assumed, despite from the performance, that I also get for consistency one all entries since it must query the whole token range.

Second issue, when I add a secondary index in this case to location, and do a query like select * from test_storage where location=1 I also get random results wiht consistency one. And always correct results when changing to consistency level local_quorum. Also here I don't understand why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When changing consistency to local_quorum I always get back the complete result. Why is this so?

Welcome to the eventual consistency world. To understand it, read my slides: http://www.slideshare.net/doanduyhai/cassandra-introduction-2016-60292046/31

> I assumed, despite from the performance, that I also get for consistency one all entries since it must query the whole token range

Yes, Cassandra will query all token ranges because of the non restricted `SELECT *` but it will only request data from one replicas out of 2 (RF=2)

> and do a query like select * from test_storage where location=1 I also get random results wiht consistency one

Same answer as above, native Cassandra secondary index is just using a Cassandra table under the hood to store the reverse-index so the same eventual consistency rules apply there too